# How many sets of positive integers $(a,b,c,d)$ for $a^3+b^3 = c^3+d^3$?

Tags: combinatorics

Four distinct positive integers  $a, b, c, d$ satisfy the equation $a^3+b^3 = c^3+d^3$ .
An example for $(a,b,c,d)$ is $(9,10,1,12)$ as $9^3+10^3 = 1^3+12^3$.
Is there an infinite number of such examples for $(a,b,c,d)$? If there is no an infinite number of examples for $(a,b,c,d)$ then how many?

Comment: Multiply any solution throughout with a positive number to get another solution. So there are an infinite solutions unless you restrict these.

Comment: $(a,a,a,a)$ works for all $a$

Comment: Request OP to first check for similar problems before posting a problem. Math.SE has a lot of such known problems already posted and with solutions.

Comment: 24153319581254312065344 can be expressed as the sum of two cubes in six different ways.

Comment: See [**Leonhard Euler**, *Disquitiones Artithmeticae*, Vol. I, Ch. $272$, Pag. $556-576$](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6952c/f599.highres).